# Which hardware RAID 5+ cards have a true separation between Host CPU and controller CPU ops?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hardware-raid

For example, Windows talks with the 3Ware card as if it were a hard drive, and the 3Ware card takes care of writing content to the raid as an asynchronous process.  This frees up the CPU from disk operations.

Including 3Ware, what Server raid cards should I consider that truly separate raid operations from the server?  Contrary to popular believe, it's very hard to find cards that actually do this similar to 3ware.

Comment: "Contrary to popular believe, it's very hard to find cards that actually do this similar to 3ware." I strongly disagree. There's a reasonably obvious price difference between the hardware RAID HBAs and the fake-RAID (software based) impostors.

Comment: I agree. "Hard to find" means "clueless about the major brands". There are a handfull, well known.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it's hard at all, look at Adaptec, HP, IBM, Dell, Sun and LSI to name a few, they all make purely hardware driven disk controllers.

Comment: Just a remark: The Dell PERC 5/i, 6/i, H700, H800 and other Dell RAID controllers are revamped (OEMd) LSI RAID controllers.

Answer (score 1):

pretty much any hardware raid card that has a BBU option.  Try LSI, Adaptec, most Dell PERC, Intel, HP, etc.